# Can I use SIP to generate Python binding for my Qt C++ library then call it in PySide?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyside, python-sip

I have to choose PySide due to the license. But its Shiboken tool is so lack of documentations. I can't successfuly generate a binding for my Qt C++ libraries.

Looks like SIP is more mature at least on the documentation part. Is it possible for me to generate the binding using SIP, then run my python code on PySide to call the binding? My users environment would be Windows XP + Python 2.7 + PySide 1.1.2 (Window installer based, installed to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide).

Comment: I'm afraid the answer would be no, you should use Shiboken for PySide.